# JSON Jackson Annotations Ignored

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using @JsonIgnore and still getting StackoverflowError.

There's a cycle and the annotation is ignored.

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Buch.findAll", query="SELECT b FROM Buch v")
public class Buch implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    ...

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Titel
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="buch")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Titel Titel;

    ...

    @JsonIgnore
    public Titel getTitel() {
        return this.verein;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setTitel(Titel titel) {
        this.titel= titel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider posting the actual code and the actual stack trace that produces. Consider extracting an equivalent but shorter/condensed example of the code demonstrating the issue from the project you are working on, if it's a lot of code. (I.e. a self contained code example.) Finally, you as a matter of program design you may also want to decouple the model logic (with @Entity annotations) from the input/output serialisation format (with Jackson annotations) into separate classes and convert between the two types as and when needed. That way you can simplify.

Comment: by the way the relation is OneToOne not many-to-one as you say in the comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Well there are several problems in your code:

- You are using `@JsonIgnore` annotation with both field and its
  accessors(getter and setter), you should't do that, mapping only one
  of them is sufficient. I suggest you map only the getter method with
  `@JsonIgnore`.
- Another thing is that your `Titel`'s `getter` method is not correctly
  implemented, it should return `Titel` field but you are returning
  `this.verein`, this is totally wrong and will mess up the logic of
  your code, you need to    correct it.

What I suggest here is to use `@JsonIgnore` **only** with the getter method which you need to correct:

```
@JsonIgnore
public Titel getTitel() {
    return this.Titel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this code will not work the title will not set by (jackson ex) because you're making a @JsonIgnore on a setter change it with @JsonSetter and on your getters add @JsonIgnore :

```
@JsonIgnore
public Titel getTitel() {
    return this.verein;
}

@JsonSetter
public void setTitel(Titel titel) {
    this.titel= titel;
}
```